# TeXstudio - citations show as a question mark only in a newly inserted file

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, citing

This is my preamble. You can see that I want to include various TeX files using the \include{} approach. I am using Bibtex for my referencing.

Issue: Citations are added correctly for the first two "includes" but from the third one, all citations appear as questions marks.

Any help to fix this would be really appreciated!

[image: preamble]

[image: with correct citation]

[image: with a ? in the next "include"]

Comment: Did you run `bibtex` again?

Comment: Hi. Yes but it didn't change anything.

Comment: And after that, did you run `pdflatex` again? Also, check if you are citing the right biblabel.